# how to check for html5/css3 compliant web pages

Tags: html, css, plugins, open-source

We are building web based application front end for a web based application using HTML5/CSS3/JQUERY. We are using firebug at the moment which is not helping us good. I would like to know how can i ensure the pages are html5/css3 compliant. I am also looking for a plugin like firebug, which will help my team to make sure we are following best practices and while building quality front end for web based application for fortune 500 client.

If i could get a plugin or any link to web based open source application will be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always want to run tests on here towards the end. But you can also run them periodically.

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: i tried the addon mentioned by Lt_Shade, but it didnt work out :(

Comment: Thats a pity. But with codehorse's way you won't go wrong.

Comment: [This](https://html5test.com/) is a nice website to check what all HTML5 features are currently supported in the browser from which you browser the url. This can help decide what all HTML5 tags should be used in website development w.r.t. target user base even before someone starts building an HTML5 compliant website.

Answer (score 2):

As *codehorse* has said you can validate them on w3.org. There is an add on for firebug which can do this for you (I have never used it). https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/validator/

Just found this one while I was looking at other stuff
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-5-validator/?src=ss yet again not sure if it works.